# How to declare a global integer instance in LLVM IR?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I was wondering if anyone knew how to declare a global integer instance in LLVM IR. So far, I've been doing the following:

```
// Create symbol to identify previous block. Added by Justin.
llvm::Type::TypeID stupidTypeID = llvm::Type::IntegerTyID;
llvm::Type* typePtr = llvm::Type::getPrimitiveType(_context, stupidTypeID);
llvm::GlobalVariable* prevBlockID = new llvm::GlobalVariable(typePtr,
                                                           false,
                                                          llvm::GlobalValue::LinkerPrivateLinkage,
                                                           NULL,
                                                           "PREV_BLOCK_ID");
```

When I try to run, I get the following error:

```
static llvm::PointerType* llvm::PointerType::get(llvm::Type*, unsigned int): Assertion `EltTy && "Can't get a pointer to <null> type!"' failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's due to the wrong type. You can have a look at `Type::getPrimitiveType` implementation [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/IR/Type.cpp#L26). Simply put, that's NOT the API you are advised to use; for IntegerType, it returns nullptr. Also, in definition of `TypeID` in [llvm/IR/Type.h](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/include/llvm/IR/Type.h#L50), there comments that:

> /// Note: If you add an element to this, you need to add an element to the
>     /// Type::getPrimitiveType function, or else things will break!

Basically you can generate the type by 2 approaches:

- static `get` API for the specified type
  In your case,

  ```
  IntegerType *iTy = IntegerType::get(ctx, 32);  // if it's 32bit INT
  ```
- a helper class named `TypeBuilder`
  It makes type generation more easily and universally. `TypeBuilder` is especially useful and intuitive when you need to define more complicated types, e.g, `FunctionType`, of course with the cost of compiling your source code slowly(should you care?).

  ```
  IntegerType *intType = TypeBuilder<int, false>::get(ctx);  // normal C int
  IntegerType *intTy = TypeBuilder<types::i<32>, false>::get(ctx);  // if it's 32bit INT
  ```

BTW, you can also try [ELLCC online compiler](http://ellcc.org/demo/index.cgi) to get the corresponding C++ code for generating LLVM IR of current c/c++ src, where you need to choose the target of *Output Options* as **LLVM C++ API code**. Alternatively you can try it yourself on your machine(Since internally the online compiler simply invokes `llc`):

```
llc input.ll -march=cpp -o -
```